# Can't try my app on device android

Tags: android, appcelerator

I was working and testing this app with no problem, but today i got 88 erros.
Recently updated the Appcelerator Studio and the SDK.

The errors are:

```
[ERROR] :  Failed to compile Java source files:
[ERROR] :  /Users/salinasj/Documents/Personales/ProyectosDesarrollo/Titanium/BEM/build/android/gen/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.java:2134: error: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6
[ERROR] :          public static final int 1_4a47a0db6e=0x7f020000;
[ERROR] :    (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)
[ERROR] :  /Users/salinasj/Documents/Personales/ProyectosDesarrollo/Titanium/BEM/build/android/gen/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.java:2134: error: <identifier> expected
[ERROR] :          public static final int 1_4a47a0db6e=0x7f020000;
....
...... and a lote of this erros.......
....
[ERROR] :  88 errors
```

Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.7.1.201609100950
SDK: 5.5.1 GA

Comment: Do you have an image with an _ in the name? Try removing that. And check your Java version, minimum should be 7 for windows.

Comment: hi @miga, yes, i have a lote of images with the underscore. I will remove them and try  it again. And by the way, i am using MAC.

Comment: miga, you were right !, please write the answer so i can mark it. thanks.

Comment: sure, glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any images containing _ (underscores) please rename them and compile your app again.